# Include project directory in Jest debugging via Node

Tags: node.js, jestjs, node-inspector

I'm running into some unexpected errors in my tests. I was going through [this page](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting), and added node-inspector to the Jest command. Now the issue is in my `Sources` tab, I'm only able to see `node_modules` of my project directory. Not sure how to add my whole project directory. I tried following commoands:

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --watch --verbose true
node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest ./src/index.test.js --runInBand --watch --verbose true
```

Nothing seems to work. Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Those are command line commands. You should be more specific where is that "Sources tab"

Comment: @Teneff `Sources` tab is there in chrome dev tools. Anyways, I've figured out the issue. Debug mode doesn't work in `watch` mode.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to use `--watch` argument. Jest doesn't support debug with `watch` `true`.